# exporting interactive tables and plots from jupyter notebook to html file

Tags: python, html, plot, jupyter-notebook

I Have a jupyter notbook (.ipynb format) which I want to download as HTML file so  the output can serve as a report to customers.

in the notebook, there are interactive tables like this one,

and the output of `show(MyTABLE)` is interactive like this:

[image: pic1]

However, when I try to download the notebook as HTML file, All I get is the header of the table:
[image: pic2]

If I change the `show()` to `display(HTML(dataTable[['idx','SampleID', 'SampleType', 'Class']].to_html()))`

I receive a very long output of the data:

[image: pic3]

Can be very long and with no option the search along the table or sort the table.

My first question: Is how to make an interactive HTML file when saving from jupyter notebook.

I was looking at those linkes\ tutorials :

1. [Pandas DataFrames and Series as Interactive Tables in Jupyter](https://mwouts.github.io/itables/)
2. [Exporting Interactive Jupyter Notebook to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151181/exporting-interactive-jupyter-notebook-to-html)

My second question is regarding the plot from `clustergrammer2`  package which I can not see at all after saving to html file.
this is how it looks in the notebok:
[image: pic6]

but in the html file there is only the cell of the code with no plot:

[image: pic7]

I tried to follow explanations from [Sharing your Interactive Heatmap](https://clustergrammer.readthedocs.io/interacting_with_viz.html#sharing-your-interactive-heatmap)
but it did not work.

Please share any thoughts or idea on how to solve the issue

Comment: the answer to the first question is to downgrade nbconvert package to version = 5.5. the [link](https://github.com/mwouts/itables/issues/21#issuecomment-749797908)