# when exporting Jupyter notebook to html file - can not see interactive plots with widgets

Tags: jupyter-notebook, widget, plotly-python

I have a script that creates an interactive PCA plot with a widget so the PCA.

Meaning a script that I can change the x-axis and the y-axis with a dropdown menu.

The plot **in the notebook** looks like this:
[image]

However, if download as an HTML file using the `File> Download as> html`

The plot is not displayed.
This is the script i used:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual
@interact
def scatter_plot(x=list(components_df.select_dtypes('number').columns), 
                 y=list(components_df.select_dtypes('number').columns)[1:]):
    
    fig = px.scatter(components_df, x=x , y=y ,
                 color=dataTable_1['Class'], width=1000, height=700,
                 template='presentation',
                 labels=labels, 
                 title="PCA Score Plot (PC{} vs. PC{})".format(1, 2) ,
#                  hover_name=df1.index, 
                 hover_data=['idx', 'SampleID']

                )



    fig.show(config=config)
```

If I do not use the widget (remove the parts of the black arrows from the pic)
I can create an interactive plot (with only the first two components  of the PCA) the can be displayed in HTML file ( from the notebook)

A sample data:

```
d = {0: [1, 2, 3, 2, 1], 1: [1, 4, 5, 8, 11], 2: [2, 6, 2, 3, 2],3: [4, 2, 2, 6, 2], 4: [-1, 2, 23, -2, 2], 'idx': [1, 2,3,4,5],'SampleID': ['Area: 25', 'Area: 26','Area: 27','Area: 28','Area: 29']}
components_df= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Kindly help and if any other information is needed please let me know
Many thanks!

Already checked these links and others but could not find any answers

1. [exporting-interactive-jupyter-notebook-to-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151181/exporting-interactive-jupyter-notebook-to-html)
2. [exporting-jupyter-notebook-with-plotly-to-html-not-displaying-correctly-when-off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210187/exporting-jupyter-notebook-with-plotly-to-html-not-displaying-correctly-when-off)